# primeng p-editor not able to update html

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using p-editor of primeng v11.1.0-rc.1. I want to update p-editor ngmodel value with html on `(onTextChange)="searchInput()"` event.

Template code:

```html
    <p-editor (onTextChange)="searchInput()" [(ngModel)]="text" [style]="{'height':'50px', width: '600px'}"> </p-editor>
```

Component code:

```js
    searchInput() {
        if (this.chainData.text && this.text.includes('COUPON')) {
          this.text = this.text.replace('COUPON', '<span style="color:red"> COUPON </span>');
          console.log('after ',this.text);  // -- here this.text is updated but not replaced in p-editor 
        } 
      }
```